# Ler dados do Firebase realtime databse

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-database

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em angular, e preciso ler os dados gravados no meu realtime database do firebase.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para ler todos os dados que estão dentro do objeto 9 por exemplo ?
Preciso ler esses dados e gravá-los em variáveis, para que eu possa compará-los com outros valores.

Segue o código do meu component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { QuestionarioService } from 'src/app/providers/questionario.service';
import { MenuService } from 'src/app/providers/menu.service';
import { FirebaseService } from 'src/app/modules/utils/providers/firebase.service';
import { SessionService } from 'src/app/modules/utils/providers/session.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionario',
  templateUrl: './questionario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionario.component.sass']
})

export class QuestionarioComponent implements OnInit {

 firebase:any;

 valorR:number = 0;
 valorG:number = 0;
 valorB:number = 0;
 valorA:number = 0;
 valorS:number = 0;
 valorI:number = 0;

  constructor(public questionario:QuestionarioService,
  public menu:MenuService,
  public dialog: MatDialog,
  public session: SessionService,
  private http: Http) {
    this.firebase = new FirebaseService();
   }


  ngOnInit() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);

  let url = ''
  this.http.get( url )
     .pipe( (data: Response) => data.json() ) /* Necessário converter para JSON */
     .subscribe( answers => console.log( answers ) ); 
  }



  getRadioValorR(event){
    if(event.value > this.valorR){
      this.valorR = event.value;
      }
    }


  getRadioValorB(event){
    if(event.value > this.valorB){
      this.valorB = event.value;
    }
  }

  getRadioValorA(event){
    if(event.value > this.valorA){
      this.valorA = event.value;
    }
  }
  getRadioValorS(event){
    if(event.value > this.valorS){
      this.valorS = event.value;
    }
  }

  getRadioValorI(event){
    if(event.value > this.valorI){
      this.valorI = event.value;
    }
  }

  derteminaG(){
    this.valorG = this.valorR;
    if(this.valorG < this.valorB){
      this.valorG = this.valorB;
    }
    if(this.valorG < this.valorA){
      this.valorG = this.valorA;
    }
    if(this.valorG < this.valorS){
      this.valorG = this.valorS;
    }
    if(this.valorG < this.valorI){
      this.valorG = this.valorI;
    }
   return this.valorG;
  }

  getClass0(){
    if(this.derteminaG() == 0){
      return true;
    }

  }
  getClass1(){
    if(this.derteminaG() == 1){
      return true;
    }
  }
  getClass2(){
    if(this.derteminaG() == 2){
      return true;
    }
  }
  getClass3(){
    if(this.derteminaG() == 3){
      return true;
    }
  }

    Desabilitar(element){
    var radio = document.getElementById(element) as HTMLInputElement;
    if(radio.style.display == 'none'){
      radio.style.display = 'table-cell';
    }else radio.style.display = 'none';
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra isso você precisa utilizar o modulo Http do angular para fazer uma requisição para sua tabela no firebase e assim extrair o valor desejado.

### Primeiro passo: importar o módulo Http dentro do seu app.module.ts

```
/* app.module.ts*/

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


...

imports[
  ...
  HttpModule      /* Adicionar o HttpModule dentro de imports */
]
```

### Segundo passo: Importar o Http dentro do componente que quer fazer a requisição e iniciar setup

**Leia os comentários no código para entender cada passo**

```
...

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
/* Importa o Http e também o tipo Response */

constructor( private http: Http) {} // Adicione o módulo ao seu constructor

ngOnInit() {
     /* O método GET retorna os dados da sua requisição */
     /* Você precisa passar a URL do seu banco de dados no Firebase como parametro*/

     /* As URLs do Firebase geralmente tem esse formato: 
      *  https://nomeprojeto-18e6c.firebaseio.com/recipes.json
      */

    let url = 'https://nomeprojeto-18e6c.firebaseio.com/nomebanco.json'
     this.http.get( url )
     .pipe( (data: Response) => data.json() ) /* Necessário converter para JSON */
     .subscribe( answers => console.log( answers ) ); 

     /* console.log imprimirá sua tabela com os objetos 9, 10, 11*/
}
```

**INFORMAÇÕES IMPORTANTES NO SEU CONTEXTO**

Dentro do `subscribe` você pode atribuir o valor retornado para uma variável.

Vou adicionar uma propriedade acima do construsctor para ilustrar o que pode ser feito.

...

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; /* Importa o Http */



Answers: any; /* VARIÁVEL NOVA */
constructor( private http: Http) {} // Adicione o módulo ao seu constructor

ngOnInit() {
     /* O método GET retorna os dados da sua requisição */
     /* Você precisa passar a URL do seu banco de dados no Firebase como parametro*/

     /* As URLs do Firebase geralmente tem esse formato: 
      *  https://nomeprojeto-18e6c.firebaseio.com/recipes.json
      */

    let url = 'https://nomeprojeto-18e6c.firebaseio.com/nomebanco.json'
     this.http.get( url )
     .pipe( data => data.json() ) /* Necessário converter para JSON */
     .subscribe( answers => {
         this.answers = answers 
     }); 

     /* console.log imprimirá sua tabela com os objetos 9, 10, 11*/
}
```

Comment: Se eu quiser retornar apenas o objeto 9 por exemplo, basta eu trocar answers por 9 ?

Comment: Como o retorno será um objeto você pode acessar através da chave do objeto. Nesse caso, this.answers.9.

Comment: O seguinte erro foi retornado após eu inserir seu código :
 "message": "A propriedade 'json' não existe no tipo 'Observable<Response>'.

Comment: Não está funcionando :/

Comment: Tá, na linha onde tem .pipe( data => data.json() ) substitua por isso: 

.pipe( (data:any) => data.json() )

O correto é adicionar o tipo response no retorno, mas vou atualizar o código com mais calma em breve

Comment: Fiz a substituição e o erro sumiu, porém assim que a pagina é carregada e o código é chamado dentro do ngOnInit(), a aplicação quebra ...

Comment: Este é o erro retornado : 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[QuestionarioComponent -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[QuestionarioComponent -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[QuestionarioComponent -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[QuestionarioComponent -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get

Comment: Talvez tenha alguma outra lógica do seu código conflitando com o que sugeri. O ideal é você editar sua pergunta e adicionar o que você tem aí pra ficar mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: @JVM Ah, tem mais uma coisinha. É necessário importar o modulo Http dentro do seu App.module.ts 

Vou atualizar a resposta para ficar melhor a leitura, ok? Dá uma olhada em uns 2 minutos.

Comment: @JVM Código atualizado. Acredito que agora vá funcionar!

Comment: Retornou um erro encima do Response.
Vou atualizar a pergunta q postar meu código pra ver se você consegue me ajudar.

Comment: Não sei se o erro está só no exemplo que você colou ou no seu código, mas você precisa adicionar sua URL e organizar o código desta forma:

 `let url = "SUA URL"
  this.http.get( url ) .pipe( (data: Response) => data.json() ) 
    .subscribe( 
      answers => console.log( answers ) ); }`

Comment: Eu vou precisar sair aqui agora, infelizmente. Espero ter ajudado até um certo ponto. Estou percebendo que você está tendo bastante dificuldade com conceitos básicos do Angular. Sugiro procurar algum curso online pra fazer um acompanhamento, vai ser mais produtivo pra você. Boa sorte e não desista!

Comment: Eu só tirei a URL pra postar o código aqui, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 0):

Utilize na sua função :

```
  var key: string;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  return this.db.object("9" + key).snapshotChanges()
  .map(c => {
    return { key: c.key, ...c.payload.val() };
  });
})
```